# How to throttle events in bloc?

Tags: flutter, dart, reactive-programming, bloc, state-management

How to throttle events in bloc? Let's say, I want to trigger file save on user input, but perform file system access not more often than once per 100ms?

Example bloc event handler:

```dart
on<StoreFile>(_handleStoreEvent);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Each handler have an optional `transformer:` field which can do throttling (and much more).

Using [rxdart](https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart) you can implement throttling yourself:

```dart
on<StoreFile>(
  _handleStoreEvent,
  transformer: (events, mapper) => events.throttleTime(Duration(milliseconds: 100)).switchMap(mapper),
);
```

I wrote the [bloc_event_transformers](https://pub.dev/packages/bloc_event_transformers) package to do popular transforms like throttle and debounce to reduce the boilerplate in my apps. It can be used like that:

```dart
on<StoreFile>(
  _handleStoreEvent,
  transformer: throttle(Duration(milliseconds: 100)),
);
```