# How to debounce events in bloc?

Tags: flutter, dart, reactive-programming, bloc, state-management

How to debounce events in bloc? Let's say, I want to perform a search query on a backend, but before doing that wait for the user to stop typing? By "stop typing" I mean 1 second period until last key was pressed.

Example bloc event handler:

```dart
on<Search>(_handleSearchEvent);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each handler have an optional `transformer:` field which can do debouncing (and much more).

Using [rxdart](https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart) you can implement debouncing yourself:

```dart
on<Search>(
  _handleSearchEvent,
  transformer: (events, mapper) => events.debounceTime(Duration(seconds: 1)).switchMap(mapper),
);
```

I wrote the [bloc_event_transformers](https://pub.dev/packages/bloc_event_transformers) package to do popular transforms like throttle and debounce to reduce the boilerplate in my apps. It can be used like that:

```dart
on<Search>(
  _handleSearchEvent,
  transformer: debounce(Duration(seconds: 1)),
);
```

Comment: Looks promising… but you had a question about debouncing events in bloc and one minute later you came up with your own dart package? That was fast :D There is also https://pub.dev/packages/stream_transform – which might be interesting.

Comment: I made the package after discussing the issue with the bloclibrary.dev author on [twitter](https://twitter.com/wrbl_xyz/status/1490355424322891780). This question was posted with the answer (StackOverflow does support that! :D) to promote the package and/or provide the implementation basis for anyone looking for more sophisticated solution than my package provides. What's more, I did very similar thing with [throttling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71034720/how-to-throttle-events-in-bloc/71034721#71034721) :)

Comment: @MarcinWróblewski you should mark it as answered

Comment: I’ll do that as soon as StackOverflow will let me 

Comment: Inspiring! nice package ;)